# Truncate table with IF condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i want to truncate the table if data is 35 days old is there a way to put if with truncate command
table name Employee i want below output

```
truncate table employee if datediff(day,record_date,getdate()) >35
```

Comment: Truncate will remove all rows from the table. Is that your intent? You can truncate conditionally with an IF statement.

Comment: Hiya - `Truncate` would empty out the entire table, are you asking about `Delete` instead because you only want to get rid of a few rows based on your condition?

Comment: Wonder where did you get that syntax on `TRUNCATE`. Please refer to documentation if you are unsure of the correct syntax

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to delete records, not truncate the table:

```
delete from employee
    where record_date < dateadd(day, -35, convert(date, getdate()));
```

Note:  If the table is a large table, then you might want to consider storing the data using *partitioning*.  This allows you to drop partitions, which is typically much faster than deleting large numbers of records.

Comment: Thank you : i want to  truncate the table only as every month needs fresh data in that table there should not be any previous records i think above code should work for that also

Comment: @ishaarora . . . If the table is large, you might find that partitioning the table (perhaps by week) is the most efficient approach -- it would allow you to just drop partitions on a regular schedule.  But if the table is not large (that less less than a few million rows), your approach is probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't truncate, you just use a `DELETE` query.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

For SQL server, the query should be:

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE datediff(day, GETDATE(), record_date) > 35
```

For MariaDB / mySQL, the `DATEDIFF()` function only takes two arguments, because it's returning days by default:

```
DELETE FROM `employee` WHERE DATEDIFF(now(), `record_date`) > 35
```

The `TRUNCATE` statement is defined as follows:

> In SQL, the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement is a Data Definition Language
> (DDL) operation that marks the extents of a table for deallocation
> (empty for reuse). The result of this operation quickly removes all
> data from a table, typically bypassing a number of integrity enforcing
> mechanisms. It was officially introduced in the SQL:2008 standard.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_(SQL)

Comment: Thank you will try the same